# Amazon S3 parallel download bandwidth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does anyone know what happens when 10.000 or more users paralell downloading files from a amazon s3 server ?
will the bandwith be decrased ?
or can all of the 10.000+ users download the files with the maximum bandwidth ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377086/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-bandwidth-used-by-amazon-s3) there are no bandwidth limits. Moreover, after searching through Amazon's tech docs and terms I found no mention of limits so any limits are not public. Searching the web also shows no results on bandwidth limiting policies. Also, since Amazon makes money on bandwidth it is not in their interest to limit it so it would be logical that they wouldn't.

There is a [blog post](http://improve.dk/pushing-the-limits-of-amazon-s3-upload-performance/) benchmarking Amazon's network that shows they have massive amounts of redundant bandwidth and that in general the network scales well without any noticeable degradation.

Bandwidth limitations are very unlikely to come from Amazon but rather from residential and cellular ISPs who limit their bandwidth to serve many low-paying customers. Amazon's data-centers are on massively overbuilt Internet backbones and will not be the cause of bottlenecks.

Comment: That said, you are likely better off serving the file via cloudfront than directly from s3. Since the file is distributed you would likely have better overall performance.